# How to increment a variable inside CASE WHEN clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make a new column with a variable that increments given a condition clause.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
     [timestamp], 
     [load], 
     [timestamp] % 60 AS module, 
     group_by_column = CASE WHEN ([timestamp] % 60)= 0 then 1 else 0 end  
FROM 
     table_01
```

And this is my return:

```
    timestamp load module group_by_column
    1432592618 24 38 0
    1432592619 32 39 0
    1432592620 21 40 0
    1432592621 31 41 0
    1432592622 28 42 0
    1432592640 22 0 1
    1432592641 31 1 0
    1432592642 39 2 0
    1432592643 33 3 0
    1432592644 36 4 0
    1432592649 32 9 0
    1432592698 21 58 0
    1432592700 25 0 1
    1432592701 20 1 0
    1432592702 27 2 0
    1432592703 31 3 0
```

I need a table like this:

```
    timestamp load module group_by_column
    1432592618 24 38 0
    1432592619 32 39 0
    1432592620 21 40 0
    1432592621 31 41 0
    1432592622 28 42 0
    1432592640 22 0 1
    1432592641 31 1 1
    1432592642 39 2 1
    1432592643 33 3 1
    1432592644 36 4 1
    1432592649 32 9 1
    1432592698 21 58 1
    1432592700 25 0 2
    1432592701 20 1 2
    1432592702 27 2 2
    1432592703 31 3 2
```

For Example, every time I found the condition [timestamp] % 60 = 0 is satisfied, I increment in the forth column.

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this problem, I just need an output as described below.

Thanks

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return one of several values - but it's **not** designed to execute code and do things like update variables or stuff like that ...

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would do a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT [timestamp],  [load],  [timestamp] % 60 AS module, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN [timestamp] % 60 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
           (ORDER BY timestamp) as group_by_column
FROM table_01;
```

In SQL Server 2008, I think you can get the same effect using `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT [timestamp],  [load],  [timestamp] % 60 AS module, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [timestamp] / 60) 
FROM table_01;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the counting integer should reflect the minutes that have passed since the first event, then the following will work:

```
SELECT [timestamp],  [load],  [timestamp] % 60 AS module, 
   ([timestamp] / 60) - (SELECT min([timestamp]) / 60 FROM table_01) grp
FROM table_01;
```